# UIViewController present another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I Have a UIViewController 1 on it UIButton (added as subview), after I pressed Button (see pic.1 below) on it adding another UIViewController 2 with animation from the bottom to top after some action:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.view];
```

And it overlaps `UIButton`, how can I add this subview that it does not cover `UIButton`(see pic.2 below)

pic.1:

[image]

pic. 2:

[image]

Comment: What about to set frame for view?

Comment: not working, if I present UIView without animation may be it will be working, needs other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the animation code but I assume you add the subview off-screen, then change it's frame (animated) to slide it into view.

Add the new subview using `insertSubview:belowSubview:` instead, passing your button as the second argument. This way the button will overlap the new view, instead of the other way round. `addSubview:` always puts the new view on top of any others.

**EDIT**

From your comments it seems that you're adding the second view controller to the screen using `presentModalViewController:` so the above method won't work. As far as I know there is no way to keep an element from the original view controller on top of the new view controller's view if you are presenting it this way.

You may have to create a new `UIWindow` and set it's `windowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelAlert` to hold your button. This will keep it on top of any of the views underneath. Add this window as a subview to the main window.

Comment: This method does not working for me. I need to add UIViewController 2 with animation without overlapping Button, on other UIViewController 1.

Comment: Oh right, so you're presenting the second view controller modally, and you want it to underlap a subview of your first view controller?

Comment: I have resolved this problem by creating fake button on UIViewController 2. I just thought that there is another way to do this. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
SecondViewController *objComing=[[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:objComing.view];

objComing.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

objComing.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,420, 320, 0);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
objComing.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 420);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Put this code in the button action and replace secondViewController with your ViewController.